# sqlitedatabase update

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm currently trying to update a row using the [`sqlitedatabase.update` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) here:

Heres the code that I have:

```
public int udpateStockInfo(String stock, double qty, double purchasePrice){
    ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
    val.put(KEY_QTY, qty);
    val.put(KEY_PURCHASE_PRICE, purchasePrice);

    return db.update(DB_TABLE, val, KEY_STOCKNAME + "=?", new String[]{stock});  
}
```

Right now I'm getting an error on the last return line. Can anyone help me with it? The IDE is saying there is a syntax error on tokens, misplaced constructs.

Comment: `new String[]{stock}`. Missing the new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as noted above gotta make sure its' a new String[]